# Error In My Code : A TOP N or FETCH rowcount value may not be negative

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting this error > A TOP N or FETCH rowcount value may not be negative.

I am getting this error in this section of the code. Please Help  >>

```
Select 
            A2.Employee_Name,
            A2.User_Name,
            A2.User_Code,
            A2.User_Type_Name,
            A2.Region_Name,
            A2.Region_Code,
            A2.Division_Name,
            [A3.Day_Count]-[A2.Sunday]-[A2.Holiday] "Total_Days",
            IsNull(A4.Reported_Days,0) "Reported_Days",
            IsNUll((A5.Non_Reported_Days)-IsNull((A6.Holiday_Count),0),0) "Non_Reported_Days",
            Round((Convert(Float,(A4.Reported_Days))/Convert(Float,((A3.Day_Count)-(A2.Sunday)-(A2.Holiday)))*100),0) "Percentage"
            From
            (
            Select 
            A1.Employee_Name,
            A1.User_Name,
            A1.User_Code,
            A1.User_Type_Name,
            A1.Region_Name,
            A1.Region_Code,
            A1.Division_Name,
            Sum(Case When A1.Days = 1 And A1.Holiday = ''0'' Then 1 Else 0 End) "Sunday",
            Sum(Case When A1.Holiday <> ''0'' Then 1 Else 0 End) "Holiday"
            From
            (
            Select 
            E.Employee_Name,
            U.User_Code,
            U.User_Name,
            UT.User_Type_Name,
            R.Region_Name,
            R.Region_Code,
            D.Division_Name,
            Datepart(W,D1.Date_Val) "Days",
            IsNull(H.Holiday_Name,0)"Holiday"
            From
            Tbl_Sfa_User_Master U With(Nolock)
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_Employee_Master E With(Nolock) On (E.Employee_Code = U.Employee_Code)
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_User_Type_Master UT With(Nolock) On (UT.User_Type_Code = U.User_Type_Code and  UT.User_Type_Category <> ''NON_FIELD_USER'')
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_Region_Master R With(Nolock) On (R.Region_Code = U.Region_Code And R.Region_Status=1)
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_Division_Entity_Mapping DE With(Nolock) On (DE.Entity_Code = U.User_Code And DE.Entity_Type=''User'')
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_Division_Master D With(Nolock) On (D.Division_Code = DE.Division_Code And D.Record_Status=1'

            If @Division_Name <> ''

            Set @Ins_Tbl = @Ins_Tbl + 'And D.Division_Name ='''+@Division_Name+''' '

            Set @Ins_Tbl = @Ins_Tbl +')

            Inner Join @DW D1 On (1=1)
            Left Outer Join Tbl_Sfa_Holiday_Master H With(Nolock) On (H.Region_Code = R.Region_Code and Convert(Date,H.Holiday_Date) = D1.Date_Val And H.Holiday_Status = 0)
            Where U.User_Status=1
            )A1
            Group By
            A1.Employee_Name,
            A1.User_Code,
            A1.User_Name,
            A1.User_Type_Name,
            A1.Region_Name,
            A1.Region_Code,
            A1.Division_Name)A2
            Left Outer Join
            (Select 
            B.User_Code,
            Count(A.Date_Val) "Day_Count"
            From
            @DW A
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_User_Master B With(Nolock) On (1=1)
            Where B.User_Status=1
            Group By B.User_Code) A3 On (A3.User_Code = A2.User_Code)
            Left Outer Join 
            (Select 
            U.User_Code,
            Count(Distinct D.DCR_Code) "Reported_Days"
            From 
            @R_Days A 
            Inner Join Tbl_sfa_User_Master U With(Nolock) On (1=1)
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_User_Type_Master UT With(Nolock) On (UT.User_Type_Code = U.User_Type_Code And User_Type_Category <> ''NON_FIELD_USER'')
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_DCR_Master D With(Nolock) On (D.User_Code = U.User_Code And D.DCR_Actual_Date = A.Date_Val And D.DCR_Status In (''1'',''2''))
            Where U.User_Status=1
            Group By U.User_Code)A4 On (A4.User_Code = A2.User_Code)
            Left Outer Join 
            (Select 
            U.User_Code,
            Sum(Case When A.Date_Val=D.DCR_Actual_Date Then 0 Else 1 End) "Non_Reported_Days"
            From 
            @R_Days A 
            Inner Join Tbl_sfa_User_Master U With(Nolock) On (1=1)
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_User_Type_Master UT With(Nolock) On (UT.User_Type_Code = U.User_Type_Code And User_Type_Category <> ''NON_FIELD_USER'')
            Left Outer Join Tbl_Sfa_DCR_Master D With(Nolock) On (D.User_Code = U.User_Code And D.DCR_Actual_Date = A.Date_Val And D.DCR_Status In (''1'',''2''))
            Where U.User_Status=1
            Group By U.User_Code)A5 On (A5.User_Code = A2.User_Code)
            Left Outer Join 
            (Select 
            U.User_Code,
            Count(H.Holiday_Code) "Holiday_Count"
            From
            Tbl_Sfa_User_Master U
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_Region_Master R On (R.Region_Code = U.Region_Code And R.Region_Status=1)
            Inner Join Tbl_Sfa_Holiday_Master H On (H.Region_Code = R.Region_Code And H.Holiday_Date Between '''+@Start_Date+''' and '''+@End_Date+''' and H.Holiday_Status=''0'')
            Where U.User_Status=1
            Group By 
            U.User_Code)A6 On (A6.User_Code = A5.User_Code)
```

Comment: You can't just stop like that in the middle of query and through in an IF statement. And what in the world are those ridiculous joins where 1 = 1??? Have you heard about cross joins? That sounds like what you want instead. You might also consider reading this article before you continue to litter your database with nolock hints. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ The formatting of this makes it nearly impossible to decipher most of it.

Comment: Looks like a part of dynamic sql construction. Check quotes and parenthesis.

Comment: Do you think that maybe, given the error message talks about two features (`TOP` and `FETCH`), and your example code contains *neither*, that maybe you haven't properly isolated the source of your errors? Try to cut out a lot of the noise here if you want help (e.g. do you get the same error when you're only selecting 1 column rather than 20?)

Answer (score 0):

looks like the issue is here with the syntax,

```
Set @Ins_Tbl = @Ins_Tbl + 'And D.Division_Name ='''+@Division_Name+''' '
```

you should have a space between ' and And as,

```
Set @Ins_Tbl = @Ins_Tbl + ' And D.Division_Name ='''+@Division_Name+''' '
```

try it if this works